# Is there a way to set the status of an incoming Whatsapp Message as read through Twilio API?

Tags: javascript, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I can set the read status of a whatsapp message through the meta API: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/mark-message-as-read](https://stackoverflow.com)

However, I can't seem to find if there is a way to do it through twilio api.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Would be incredibly useful :)

I tried using the update method here: [https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api/message-resource#update-a-message-resource](https://stackoverflow.com), but that is only for certain use cases listed here

```
Updates the body of a Message resource. Send a POST request to a Message resource's URI containing the updated parameters.

This action is primarily used to redact Message content. To redact a Message resources's Body, send a POST request to the Message resource's URI and set the Body parameter as an empty string: "". This redacts the Body of a message while keeping the other Message resource properties intact.
```

Answer (score 1):

The read recipes/blue checkmarks you have mentioned is currently not supported. Our team is continually working on improving and expanding our offerings for future updates.